# Error during Swift standalone install [error in setup command: Invalid environment marker python version>=3.0]

Tags: python, openstack-swift

I have been trying to do the manual install of Openstack Swift (SAIO) as detailed here:

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html

However, when I get to the point where I need to build swift using the command:

```
sudo python setup.py develop
```

I get the following error:

```
error in setup command: Invalid environment marker python version>=3.0
```

I've followed all the other instructions to a T and they've passed without any errors, but I can't work out why/what is demanding a python version>=3.0

My own version of python is 2.7.6

I'd appreciate some help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Looking through the files for the string `python_version` (using command `grep -R python_version ./*`) I found out that it was only present in the file `requirements.txt`:

```
./requirements.txt:dnspython>=1.12.0;python_version<'3.0'
./requirements.txt:dnspython3>=1.12.0;python_version>='3.0'
```

Since I am not using Python 3, I edited `requirements.txt` and commented out the second line, and removed `python_version<'3.0'` from the first.

That solved the problem for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying `requirements.txt` file you can try to upgrade `pip` and `virtualenv` if you are using it.

```
pip install -U pip
pip install -U virtualenv
```